# R: choosing elements of dataframe by condition

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I'm new in R, and I have dataframe with some data. I have some conditional functions, returning `True` or `False`, and I want to choose elements of dataframe that will have all `True`.

```
frame:
    V1    V2   V3   V4
1:  "abc" 6    4    1b2
2:  kk    wq2 "3 4" 8
```

For example:

```
first_func <- function(x) is.digit(x) # will choose all numerics
second_func <- function(x) x > 5 # will choose only numbers > 5
```

I want to choose all elements `> 5`, and apply another function for them, for example

```
third_function <- function(x) x^2 # for only numbers > 5 get square
```

I want to get this result:

```
frame:
    V1    V2  V3   V4
1:  "abc" 36  4    1b2
2:  kk    wq "3 4" 64
```

How can I do it correctly using R syntax?

Comment: Can you share reproducible example using dput() and expected output

Comment: Can you please format your sample data, using column names and indentation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach with `apply()` and a built-in function:

```
#Code
myfun <- function(x)
{
  y <- as.numeric(x)
  z <- ifelse(!is.na(y) & y>5,y^2,x)
  return(z)
}
#Apply
Res <- as.data.frame(t(apply(df,1,myfun)))
```

Output:

```
Res
   V1  V2  V3  V4
1 abc  36   4 1b2
2  kk wq2 3 4  64
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("abc", "kk"), V2 = c("6", "wq2"), V3 = c("4", 
"3 4"), V4 = c("1b2", "8")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Same approach can be obtained with `sapply()`:

```
#Code 2
Res2 <- as.data.frame(sapply(df,myfun))
```

Output:

```
Res2
   V1  V2  V3  V4
1 abc  36   4 1b2
2  kk wq2 3 4  64
```

Comment: it doesn't work if functions are not so simple, I need to know how basicly choose values for any conditions `True` or `False`

Comment: @Angelika I do not understand what functions do you refer, could you please elaborate?